# Condition for which $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=K\in\mathbb{R}$ represent a circle

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, circles

> Let $K\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$.
>
> Prove that the equation $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=K$ represent a circle iff $K\geq\frac{1}{2}|z_1-z_2|^2$.

**My Attempt**
$$
|z|^2+|z_1|^2-2\mathcal{Re}(z\bar{z}_1)+|z|^2+|z_2|^2-2\mathcal{Re}(z\bar{z}_2)=K\\
2|z|^2+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-2\bigg[\mathcal{Re}(z\bar{z}_1)+\mathcal{Re}(z\bar{z}_2)\bigg]=K\\
2|z|^2+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-2\bigg[ a_1x+b_1y+a_2x+b_2y \bigg]=K\\
2|z|^2+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-2\mathcal{Re}\bigg[ z\bar{z}_1+z\bar{z}_2 \bigg]=K\\
2|z|^2+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-2\mathcal{Re}\bigg[ z(\bar{z}_1+\bar{z}_2) \bigg]=K\\
|z|^2+\frac{1}{2}(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)-2\mathcal{Re}\Big(z.\frac{\bar{z}_1+\bar{z}_2}{2}\Big)=\frac{K}{2}\\
|z|^2+\frac{1}{2}(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)+\Big|\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\Big|^2-2\mathcal{Re}\Big(z.\frac{\bar{z}_1+\bar{z}_2}{2}\Big)=\frac{K}{2}+\Big|\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\Big|^2\\
|z|^2+\big|\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\big|^2-2\mathcal{Re}\Big(z.\frac{\bar{z}_1+\bar{z}_2}{2}\Big)=\frac{K}{2}+\Big|\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\Big|^2-\frac{1}{2}(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)\\
\Big|z-\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\Big|^2=\frac{K}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(z_1\bar{z}_2+\bar{z}_1z_2)=\frac{K}{2}+\frac{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2}{4}+\frac{z_1\bar{z}_2+\bar{z}_1z_2}{4}-\frac{1}{2}(z_1\bar{z}_2+\bar{z}_1z_2)\\
\Big|z-\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\Big|^2=\frac{K}{2}+\frac{1}{4}(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-z_1\bar{z}_2-\bar{z}_1z_2)=\frac{K}{2}-\frac{1}{4}|z_1-z_2|^2\\
\Big|z-\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\Big|^2=\frac{1}{4}\Big[2K-|z_1-z_2|^2\Big]\\
\implies 2K\geq|z_1-z_2|^2\implies \boxed{K\geq\frac{1}{2}|z_1-z_2|^2}
$$

As it was asked as a multiple choice question I think my attempt is a bit long and cumbersome. So, is there an easier way to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if point $T$ is for $z$ and $A,B$ for $z_1,z_2$ then we have

$$ AT^2+BT^2=K$$

Let $M = (A+B)/2$ be a midpoint for $AB$ then we have:
$$ K=  (T-A)^2+(T-B)^2$$ $$ = 2T^2-2T(A+B)+A^2+B^2 $$ $$ = 2T^2-4T\cdot M + 2M^2- 2M^2+A^2+B^2$$

$$ = 2(T-M)^2+(A-B)^2/2$$

So $$ (T-M)^2= K-(A-B)^2/4$$

and thus $4K \geq (A-B)^2$ or c) on your answer sheet.

Comment: Thanx and I just tried to modify OP to better explain my doubt. btw still trying to understand ur proof.

Comment: You just have to know position vectors.

Comment: How do u write $(T−A)^2$ for $|z−z1|^2$ ?. are u considering for the case where it is real ?. ould u pls explain a bit more.

Comment: Do you know vectors?

Comment: If $T$ is a point with coordinates $(x,y)$ then with same notation $T$ is vector from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$. So we have $\vec {T} = (x,y) =T$

Comment: And $$|z-z_1|^2 = AT^2 = \vec{AT}^2 = (T-A)^2$$